# Gnuplot freezes on set print "file.txt"

Tags: gnuplot

I am executing gnuplot script and my file ends like:

```
...
set print "fit.txt"
print myvariable
set print "some_other_file.txt"
exit
```

however it doesn't give desired result - variable value written in file. The file instead consist of

```
====Command End====
```

And it looks like my script have not ended executing, from analysis it looks like it did not get over the line'
    set print "fit.txt"'

Any ideas? I am using gnuplot editor on windows.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @oliversm it could read as: 
>a = 500
>set print "file.txt"
>print a
>set print "other_file.txt"
>exit
, but my problem is it does not work :-\

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me as expected. So it's hard to figure out what's going wrong. Did you try "print myvariable" at the console before redirecting to a file, to check its contents?